# Error reading .csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Opening a .csv file, all the _(underscores) are getting converted to +AF8-.

I can see that there is some kind of format issue but how to solve this.

I am getting the same error when I write a script to read a .csv file using pandas.

```
full_data = pd.read_csv('../data/full_data.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
print (full_data.info())
```

This is the output:

```
sdmax+AF8-posn    5530 non-null float64
```

sdmax_posn was read like that.

[image: Original Image]
[image: Error_Image]

Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess there was an invalue somewhere.
Do you know if an entry in particulare caused the problem?

Comment: Also, could you post a sample of the csv file itself?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Pandas issue and not an OpenOffice issue? See this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923688/openoffice-when-exporting-csv-underscores-are-replaced-with-af8

Comment: As @chthonicdaemon link suggest use `encoding='utf8'` inside pd.read_csv .

Comment: Thank you @chthonicdaemon, encoding='utf8' solved the pandas issue.

Comment: For me the solution was encoding='utf7', apparently encoding can change by accident when you open and save files in excel or libreoffice calc. I tried different encodings while opening the file in calc and then when I saw one that worked I input that in the encoding parameter of read_csv.